# Adding Java docs to Eclipse Project whlie exporting jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javadoc

So I have a Java Project in Eclipse for which I can generate a Jar file. Now I can use this jar file in other projects. However when I add this jar file to other project's build path using e.g Eclipse, it does not show any documentation.

It only works, if while generating Jar file, I also separately generate java docs, and on the user side, when I import this jar, I have to separately specify the java docs for this jar.

I just want to know, is there any way that I can export java docs and the project altogether as a single jar, so that when imported in other projects using Eclipse IDE it shows the documentation without having to import the java docs explicitly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you select the option "Export source files and resources" while exporting the jar file, you should be able to see the docs in other projects.

Comment: thanks manish, but if i just want to add class files and not actual .java files, would it still be possible this way?

Comment: No, you will have to include source files as well.

Comment: Ok fine, actually if i export docs only and then export project with class files only, the anyone can import those docs into this exported jar and it works fine while there is no .java file included in that jar, so i guess if i want it a single package i have to include .java files as well.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Eclipse looks for the source file corresponding to the class in the jar. If it finds the source, it reads the javadoc from there, otherwise you need to either provide the source archive OR javadoc archive for that jar.

Answer (score 0):

@manish approach and don't work for me. In my case the solution was different. You also try do it in four simple steps:

1. *Right click project - Export - Jar File*
2. *Right click project - Export - JavaDoc*
3. Compress JavaDoc folder with 7Zip or similar one. Rename with 'jar' extension.
4. Create folder with both and compress it. Rename with 'jar' extension as well.

Example

```
/your-library-v1.0.0.jar
  - your-library.jar 
  - your-library-doc.jar
```

Now you can Import the library (your-library-v1.0.0.jar) and Javadoc will be vailable in your projects.